# Typename included in enum declaration in StoreKit causes a compiler error

Tags: objective-c, enums, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a piece of code (with some C++ and Objective-C) and getting a compile error related to the `typedef` that can be found in Apple's StoreKit framework, in SKDownload.h:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger       
{
    SKDownloadStateWaiting,
    SKDownloadStateActive,
    SKDownloadStatePaused,
    SKDownloadStateFinished,
    SKDownloadStateFailed,
    SKDownloadStateCancelled
}
SKDownloadState;
```

What is the meaning of the `: NSInteger` bit ?

If I get rid of `: NSInteger` the code compiles and runs fine but I doubt I should have to do this kind of hack.

Comment: And your compiler version is: ??? (Hint: Apple tends to hack upon the Objective-C language, and they occasionally cut into C as well by accident...)

Comment: Whoa there @H2CO3 :p, this is a C++11 feature that _Clang_ has implemented: ["Enumerations with fixed underlying type"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#enumerations-with-a-fixed-underlying-type)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Then this is Objective-C++, right? (No, I'm not the C++ guy. :D)

Comment: I guess it's just made to inherit NSInteger operators in Objective-C++ .

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: `NSInteger` is a POD type, not a class.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, especially the link regarding the C++11 feature.

Comment: Further blog reading about this feature in ObjC: ["enum-num-num" at BNR](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/829-enum-num-num/), ["NS_ENUM and NS_OPTIONS"](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2012/11/ns_enum-and-ns_options/), and ["NS_ENUM & NS_OPTIONS"](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/)